# How do I "narrowly avoid" a shot?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

There are Treasure Hunt panels with the condition "Narrowly avoid a total of 5 (or 25, or 50) shots in Air Battles."

According to my records, I've narrowly avoided two shots so far, out of what must be at least ten hours of air battles. Getting another three by accident sounds reasonable, but not 23 or 47.

What kind of maneuvering counts as narrowly avoiding a shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *must* be gliding to "narrowly avoid" a shot. If you graze while shooting, or after shooting before you go into a glide, it doesn't count.

It also seems entirely unrelated to rolls (flicking the pad in one direction then the other). It's only about how close the shot comes to you. Although, if you're bad at grazing, doing rolls might help you get them faster.

(Now I've got 7, off to get 43 more...)

Answer (score -1):

I have been able to avoid five shots, so I think it means when you flick the circle pad in one direction, then in the opposite direction shortly after. You will go into a roll, which you can use to "Narrowly avoid shots." Hope this helps.

Comment: I've been trying _really hard_ to do this, and I'm no stranger to grazing, yet nothing seems to count. On the other hand, I got another one accidentally playing chapter 25 again, and I don't believe I did a roll at all during the chapter - if I did, it was entirely by accident.

Comment: Well, I did get all of mine by accident as well, so this is just an educated guess.